# Flutter bloc: BlocBuilder does not re-call builder method when stated state first time

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am trying to change the theme of my flutter app using bloc.
But I had a problem since the second time after the state was changed.

Sate is still updated, but the UI has not changed, the builder method has not run again

[image]

My log:

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device iPhone 11...
Restarted application in 1,386ms.
flutter: builder ThemeState
flutter: builder ThemeState
flutter: build
flutter: _ChangeThemeScreenState AppTheme.BlueDark
flutter: ThemeBloc AppTheme.BlueDark
flutter: ThemeBloc isThemeChange
flutter: builder ThemeState
flutter: _ChangeThemeScreenState AppTheme.BlueLight
flutter: ThemeBloc AppTheme.BlueLight
flutter: ThemeBloc isThemeChange
flutter: _ChangeThemeScreenState AppTheme.GreenDark
flutter: ThemeBloc AppTheme.GreenDark
flutter: ThemeBloc isThemeChange
```

my code:

```
class ThemeBloc extends Bloc<ThemeEvent, ThemeState> {
  ThemeBloc() : super(ThemeState(themeData: appThemeData[AppTheme.GreenLight]));

  @override
  Stream<ThemeState> mapEventToState(
    ThemeEvent event,
  ) async* {
    print("ThemeBloc " + (event as ThemeChanged).theme.toString());
    if (event is ThemeChanged) {
      print("ThemeBloc " +'isThemeChange');
      yield ThemeState(themeData: appThemeData[event.theme]);
    }
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => ThemeBloc(),
      child: BlocBuilder<ThemeBloc, ThemeState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          print("builder " + state.toString());
          return MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              title: 'Bitradez',
              routes: routes,
              theme: state.themeData);
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

when tab button

```
onTap: () {
                print("_ChangeThemeScreenState " + itemAppTheme.toString());
                BlocProvider.of<ThemeBloc>(context)
                    .add(ThemeChanged(theme: itemAppTheme));
              },
```

Comment: What is appThemeData? A map?

Comment: Can you show your ThemeState class? I once had a problem with the BlocBuilder not rebuilding because I wasn't settting the props correctly

Comment: not sure whether this would help. either add key to your material app or state.themData or yield different state ThemeBlueState, ThemeBlackState.

Comment: @matkv I implemented the ThemeState class just like the example I referenced, it's almost the same but it doesn't work.
link example : https://resocoder.com/2019/08/09/switch-themes-with-flutter-bloc-dynamic-theming-tutorial-dark-light-theme/

`part of 'theme_bloc.dart';

class ThemeState extends Equatable {

  final ThemeData themeData;

  ThemeState({
   required this.themeData,
  });

 override
  // TODO: implement props

  List<Object> get props => [];

}

`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `ThemeState` class, try passing your `themeData` property to the props, I am pretty sure that I had the same problem as you a while ago. As far as I understand, the value that you set for the `props` is what `bloc` actually looks at when deciding whether to rebuild your widget or not.

I think something like this should work:

```
List<Object> get props => [themeData]
```

You obviously still need yield this state correctly.